# What is the proper notation for these functions?

Tags: algorithms, notation

Some time it's hard to me distinguish between ( omega and theta) and (Big O and theta) .

Please solve these two questions and give me an approach to solve these types of questions..

What is the proper notation for these?

```
3n (log n)^2 + 2n (logn)  ∈ .....(nlogn)
3n (log n) + 6n ∈ .....(nlogn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f \in O(g)$ denotes $f$ grows by order(s) slower than $g$, while $f \in \Theta(g)$ means they grow within a const of each other...

$n \in O(n \log n)$ so $6n + 3n \log n = \Theta (n \log n)$

Can you please try your first one yourself and update if you need further help

Comment: @ReemAljunaid which of the 2 components grows faster? or do they grow at the same rate?

Comment: now i will tell you what i understated from you  that 3n (log n)^2 + 2n (logn) ∈ omega (nlogn), because 3n (log n)^2  grows by order faster than g

Comment: @ReemAljunaid yes